# angular ngResource pass additional arguments to the url

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ngresource

I have a project resource that consists of multiple task resource (similar to Facebook post and comments relationship)

When I update a project, I want to use url `/project/[project id]`. and when I update a task, I want to use url `/project/[project id]/[task id]`

Here is my project resource service:

```
angular.module('project').factory('Project', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    return $resource('project/:projectId', {
        projectId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    })
}])
```

Now I wanna define the task resource:

```
angular.module('task').factory('Task', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    return $resource('project/:projectId/:taskId', {
        projectId: '' //how can i pass in the project Id from controller? 
        taskId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    })

}])
```

In my controller, if i just update project, not its task, then I simply use:

```
    $scope.update = function() {

        $scope.project.$update(function() {
            $location.path('project/' + $scope.project._id)
        }, function(errResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message
        })
    }
```

But when I update the tasks of the project, I wanna pass in the project to construct the url. How can I do that?

Notice that project and task belong to separate modules. user can update the task in project detail page, or in task detail page.

Answer (score 5):

## Factory should look like this:

```
angular.module('task').factory('$task',function($resource){
        return $resource('project/:id/:taskid',
        {
                id: '@id',
                taskid: '@taskid'
        },{
                'update': {method: 'PUT'},
                'list': {method: 'GET'},
                'create':{method: 'POST'},
                'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
        });
});
```

## Calling this factory in controller:

```
$task.list({
    id : 1, // json prop name should be same as declared in factory
    taskid : 10
});
```

This will send ajax request to : `/project/1/10`

If you want to update task you have to give its project id.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what ur doing.

Its smarter to make first a "get" with the project module for the special one project.

If u have this Object, u can update it.

This looks like this:

```
angular.module('project').factory('Project', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    return $resource('project/:projectId', {
        projectId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        },

        get: {
            method:'GET'
            }
    })
}])




Project.get({projectId: projectId}, function(response){

//the response contains the data of the project Id 
//I cant test it now, ....check the docu.
//now u could update and take the id still from the response




})
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass it the same way you do other named params:

angular.module('task').factory('Task', ['$resource', function($resource) {

```
return $resource('project/:projectId/:taskId', {
    projectId: '@pid', 
    taskId: '@_id'
}, {
    update: {
        method: 'PUT'
    }
});
```

Your data model will then have `_id` and `pid` properties which ng will track, ie.:

```
this.projectId = 17 // or however you set it.
var task = new Task({
  _id: '213',
  pid: this.projectId
});
task.save(); // POST /project/17/213
```

See? So the second param to the $resource is params. The ones you map to your URL will go to URL, the others in request body (or query string, depends).